# Count Word XE field

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

How can I count how many times each unique XE-entry occurs in a Word document?

By Unique XE-entry I mean:

```
XE "Basel III"
XE "LCR"
XE "NSFR"
```

All of the above XE-entries are unique.

How many times each XE entry occurs in the document, even if more of them are on the same page in the document?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to insert an index into the document.

All XE entries will appear within it so you can count them there.  If you see duplicates, which will appear as e.g. `LCR EntryEntryEntry` right-clicking in the index on each `Entry` will enable you to jump back to the point of its insertion.